# Index Vectors with Factors in R

Tags: r

I have a factor RFyhat which I'm looking to convert to a numeric vector.  I've already discovered that

```
as.numeric(levels(RFyhat))[RFyhat]
```

works as desired, and I've played around a bit with this construction:

```
c(1,2,20,4,5,6,7)[RFyhat]
```

also works as expected (`RFyhat` has 7 levels).

So I understand the behavior of this construction, but I'm wondering if anyone can explain how this syntax is intended to work, or whether it is just 'syntactic sugar'.  More specifically, does `[RFyhat]` act as an index vector? If it does, how do factors generally behave when used as an index?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I believe that factors gets converted to integers when used for indexing, rather than characters or anything else.

Look at this example

```
> fac <- factor(letters[c(1,1,2,1,3,3,2,1)])
> vec <- c(b=1, a=2, c=3)
> vec[fac]
b b a b c c a b 
1 1 2 1 3 3 2 1
```

So element 1 of `fac` has returned element 1 of `vec`, regardless of the different order of names.

Personally I'd prefer `as.integer(as.character(RFyhat))` to `as.numeric(levels(RFyhat))[...]`.

Comment: `as.integer(as.character(RFyhat))` does have the behavior I'm looking for, but I'm more trying to understand how `as.numeric(levels(RFyhat))[RFyhat]` is doing what it's doing.  So each element of RFyhat is getting converted to an integer as if it were being "unleveled"? Take `c(1,20,3,4)[c(2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2)]` for example, which returns a numeric vector of 20s, which makes sense.  Why does `as.numeric(levels(RFyhat))[RFyhat]` return a numeric vector and not a factor? Is that just a peculiarity of R? Is the factor being converted to such a numeric vector as `c(2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2)`?

Comment: @Justin I think the piece you're missing is that a factor _is_ an integer vector (along with the levels). But it is literally stored as the integer codes, with just the unique levels as "lookup" values. Saves space.

Comment: Yup, that's what happens. You get a numeric vector back since you are subsetting a numeric vector with a factor that get's converted to an integer vector.

Comment: Oh...that makes a lot of sense.  Thanks for the help!